Не применяются изменения внесенные в таблицу через dbeaver
Делаю Insert данных в таблицу. При выборке через dbeaver выводит все внесенные данные, а если пробовать выбрать через psql, то таблица пустая.
С чем может быть связано?

Забыли коммит сделать?

@andreymal commit; Если вы про это, то не помогло

А таблица точно та же самая и в той же БД? )  Перепроверьте.

@CrazyElf Та же самая, в той же БД, в той же схеме
